Flutter Blue Plus Error in writing on a characteristic
Using flutter_blue_plus: ^1.33.5
I have a smartwatch code generating services and characteristics.
The smartphone connects to the smartwatch and uses "discoverServices", iterates every service and every characteristic to find one that is writable.
Whenever the writable characteristic is found it tries to write to it, but an Unknown Error is given (19).
Uint8List data = Uint8List data = Uint8List.fromList([0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04]);

Future<void> _sendDataToDevice(Uint8List data) async {

    if (connectedDevice != null) {
      try {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
        List<BluetoothService> services = await connectedDevice!.discoverServices();
        for (BluetoothService service in services) {
          print('Service: ${service.uuid}');
          for (BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic in service.characteristics) {
            print('Characteristic: ${characteristic.uuid}');
            print('Properties: ${characteristic.properties}');
            if (characteristic.properties.write || characteristic.properties.writeWithoutResponse) { //characteristic.properties.write && 
              print('Found writable characteristic');
              print('UUID: ${characteristic.uuid}');
              // Enable notifications if needed
              if (characteristic.properties.notify) {
                print('Enabling notifications');
                await characteristic.setNotifyValue(true);
              }
              
              // Write data with appropriate write type
              print('Writing data...');
              if (characteristic.properties.write) {
                await characteristic.write(data);
                print('Data sent to smartwatch with response: $data');
              } else {
                print('Characteristic does not support write with response');
              }

              print('Data sent to smartwatch: $data');
              return;
            }
          }
        }
        print('No writable characteristic found');
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error sending data: $e');
      }
    } else {
      print('No device connected');
    }
  }

Logs and error:
/flutter (15410): Connected to Galaxy Watch7 (JB0B)
I/ViewRootImpl@95c32e5[MainActivity](15410): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@95c32e5[MainActivity](15410): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/[FBP-Android](15410): [FBP] onMethodCall: discoverServices
D/BluetoothGatt(15410): discoverServices() - device: XX:XX:XX:XX:02:8E
D/BluetoothGatt(15410): onSearchComplete() = Device=XX:XX:XX:XX:02:8E Status=0
D/[FBP-Android](15410): [FBP] onServicesDiscovered:
D/[FBP-Android](15410): [FBP]   count: 4
D/[FBP-Android](15410): [FBP]   status: 0GATT_SUCCESS
D/[FBP-Android](15410): [FBP] onMethodCall: setNotifyValue
D/BluetoothGatt(15410): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
W/[FBP-Android](15410): [FBP] CCCD descriptor for characteristic not found: 2a05
I/flutter (15410): Service: 1801
I/flutter (15410): Characteristic: 2a05
I/flutter (15410): Properties: CharacteristicProperties{broadcast: false, read: false, writeWithoutResponse: false, write: false, notify: false, indicate: true, authenticatedSignedWrites: false, extendedProperties: false, notifyEncryptionRequired: false, indicateEncryptionRequired: false}
I/flutter (15410): Characteristic: 2b3a
I/flutter (15410): Properties: CharacteristicProperties{broadcast: false, read: true, writeWithoutResponse: false, write: false, notify: false, indicate: false, authenticatedSignedWrites: false, extendedProperties: false, notifyEncryptionRequired: false, indicateEncryptionRequired: false}
I/flutter (15410): Characteristic: 2b29
I/flutter (15410): Properties: CharacteristicProperties{broadcast: false, read: true, writeWithoutResponse: false, write: true, notify: false, indicate: false, authenticatedSignedWrites: false, extendedProperties: false, notifyEncryptionRequired: false, indicateEncryptionRequired: false}
I/flutter (15410): Found writable characteristic
I/flutter (15410): UUID: 2b29
I/flutter (15410): Writing data...
D/[FBP-Android](15410): [FBP] onMethodCall: writeCharacteristic
E/[FBP-Android](15410): [FBP] onCharacteristicWrite:
E/[FBP-Android](15410): [FBP]   chr: 2b29
E/[FBP-Android](15410): [FBP]   status: UNKNOWN_GATT_ERROR (19) (19)
I/flutter (15410): Error sending data: FlutterBluePlusException | writeCharacteristic | android-code: 19 | UNKNOWN_GATT_ERROR (19)

I get that error, I would like to know how to fix it, it seems that it is only on this line "await characteristic.write(data); "
